# How can I add more rows to my dataframe every several rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe looks like this:

```
ID       A          B          C
 1       0          O          1
 1       0          P          2
 1       0          Q          3
 2       0          R          1
 2       0          S          2
 2       0          T          3
 3       0          U          1
 3       0          V          2
 3       0          W          3
```

I need to add 48 new rows for each ID(I have more than 3 IDs). 
For column A: values in the 48 new cells equal to 1
For column B: values in the 48 new cells equal to the value in the last row (Q for 1, T for 2, W for 3)
For column C: values need to increase by 0.5 for 48 times starting the value in the last row.

Comment: I have 155 IDs in total. For column B and C, every ID has a different value in the last row for added content to start with. And I need to insert the new lines right after the existing ones with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you dataframe is that simple, you can use the method below. If you have a lot more ID numbers, it would be better to write a function (more details below the first solution)

```
ID <- rep(1:3, each = 3)
C <- rep(1:3, 3)
B <-  LETTERS[15:23]
DF <- data.frame(ID, "A" = 0, B, C)

# create 3 separate dataframes
DF1 <- DF [ DF$ID == 1,]
DF2 <- DF [ DF$ID == 2,]
DF3 <- DF [ DF$ID == 3,]

# apply the same routine on each dataframe
DF1[4:51, 'A'] <- 1
DF1[4:51, 'ID'] <- 1
DF1[4:51, 'B'] <- DF1[3, 'B']
DF1[4:51, 'C'] <- DF1[3, 'C'] + seq(from = 0.5,  by = 0.5,
                                length.out = 48)

DF2[4:51, 'A'] <- 1
DF2[4:51, 'ID'] <- 2
DF2[4:51, 'B'] <- DF2[3, 'B']
DF2[4:51, 'C'] <- DF2[3, 'C'] + seq(from = 0.5,  by = 0.5,
                                length.out = 48)
DF3[4:51, 'A'] <- 1
DF3[4:51, 'ID'] <- 3
DF3[4:51, 'B'] <- DF3[3, 'B']
DF3[4:51, 'C'] <- DF3[3, 'C'] + seq(from = 0.5,  by = 0.5,
                                length.out = 48)

# combine the 3 dataframe into 1
DFfinal <- rbind(DF1, DF2, DF3)
# reset the row numbers
rownames(DFfinal) <- NULL
```

If you have much more IDs that 3, it is better to write a function to split and create a DF'n' and then run that function for each ID to build the full dataframe.

```
extendIDdf <- function(df, i) {
  dfi <- df[ID == i,]
  dfi[4:51, 'A'] <- 1
  dfi[4:51, 'ID'] <- 1
  dfi[4:51, 'B'] <- dfi[3, 'B']
  dfi[4:51, 'C'] <- dfi[3, 'C'] + seq(from = 0.5,  by = 0.5,
                                      length.out = 48)
  return (dfi)
}

uniqueIDs <- unique(DF$ID)
DFF <- DF[ID == "",]  # create an empty dataframe with correct columns

for ( i in uniqueIDs) {
  DFF <- rbind(DFF,   extendIDdf(DF, i)) # create the extended dataframe for the ID == i and then amends the running dataframe with it.
}
rownames(DFF) <-  NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But what if each ID has different B and C values to start with? And I do have much more IDs than 3.

Comment: I modified my variable name *df1* to *dfi* (which is the selection of your dataframe when ID == i).  `dfi[4:51, 'B'] <- dfi[3, 'B']` means that we take the 3rd row (=last row) of the column B (whatever value that is) and copies it in the next 48 lines. `dfi[4:51, 'C'] <- dfi[3, 'C'] + seq(from = 0.5,  by = 0.5, length.out = 48)` takes the 3rd row (= last row) of column C (whatever value it is, even though in your dataset it is always 3, but it could be 3 or 4 or 42) and add incrementally 0.5 in the next 48 rows. Try it.